# Why is "an invalid argument, the conclusion of which is a tautology" not possible?

Tags: logic, deduction

A similar version of this question was answered before, ([An invalid argument, the conclusion of which is a tautology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/24861)) but I'm still a bit confused about why this is not possible. Like the other asker, I am responding to an exercise from an Intro to Logic text.

I thought of this example for a possible invalid argument with a tautology as its conclusion:

Monday was a sunny day

Tuesday was a rainy day

... On Wednesday, it will either rain or not rain.

I think this argument would be inductive, so wouldn't that make it deductively invalid? It doesn't seem like in all cases the truth of the premises would lead to a true conclusion, but since its conclusion is a tautology in this case, does that fit the definition of validity anyway?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119487/discussion-on-question-by-l-i-k-why-is-an-invalid-argument-the-conclusion-of).

Comment: According to the convention in current textbooks on FOL, "argument" is just a list of premises followed by the conclusion. It is called "valid" if the conclusion is true whenever the premises are on any substitution of non-logical terms. So if the conclusion is a tautology the argument is automatically "valid", the truth of premises is irrelevant. This does not follow the common use of "argument" as a sequence of steps according to some rules, inductive or deductive, but unfortunately it is entrenched now.

Comment: In short: "follows from" does not mean "is proven by".  Validity is just a guarantee that whenever *all* of the premises are true, then the conclusion shall be too.

Comment: There is a good answer to the same question on the Math Stack Exchange here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373918/different-definitions-of-a-valid-argument